# Symfony 5 - Two prefix

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony5

I need do something like this:

```
users1:
    resource: '@MyOwnBundle/Resources/config/routing/users.yaml'
    prefix: '/users1'

users2:
    resource: '@MyOwnBundle/Resources/config/routing/users.yaml'
    prefix: '/users2'
```

I need defined the same resource for two diferent prefix, but it doen't works, what is a good way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to do what you want.  As you probably discovered, the prefix only impacts the url's and not the route names.  So all your users2 routes will overwrite the user1 stuff.  You could probably do something if you used PHP to define routes instead of yaml.

Comment: and do you know how to create an alias of the original route? the problem is that the routes are defined in a bundle that is in vendors, maybe with an alias i can solve the problem

Comment: Unless I needed to do this quite a bit I would just create the routes in the application and be done with it.  Bit of copy/paste/refactor and the problem would be solved.